# PHP object variable not assignable but exist

Tags: php, api, object, properties

I'm facing a problem that I can't answer.
I have an object that I can var_dump and see, with all his variables, but when I try to assign one of his variable I get "Trying to get property of non-object"..

Here's the code (it's from an api):

```
     $teacher = $teachers->loadById($obj->userId); //gives an object teacher
     $firstName = $teacher->firstName; // That return the error
```

If I do a var_dump like this

```
     $teacher = $teachers->loadById($obj->userId);
     var_dump($teacher);exit;
     $firstName = $teacher->firstName;
```

I can see that it's an object with an attribute "firstName"

`var_dump()` result:

[image]

Does anyone experienced a situation like this?

I'm using PHP 5.5.12 on a local setup using wamp.

Edit: I noticed something else, this bug only occurs on my local setup. Everything works with my online test setup.. That makes it even more strange..

Comment: You don't show the code you wanted to use that has the error.

Comment: 1) the code above is a copy-paste of yr code? Maybe there is a typo in original code. 2) Are you sure that the error line is that? In the error message you have the **exact** line error.

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object" is an error which is quite descriptive - you're trying to access a property of something which isn't an object. Can you post the full code that you've tried which is producing this error?

Comment: Thank for your fast answers! The code I tried to use is in the first block. The php error I get is for the second line of it ($firstName = $teacher->firstName;). When I do the var_dump of the teacher object it confirms that it's an object with an attribute firstName (like shown in the picture). I'm sorry I can't show more from the code because of my compagny's policy, but I'm ready to answer to any questions. And thanks again for your very appreciated help